How do I get the each collaborator's permission level?
I am very new to Airtable and Airtable extensions and am trying to print out the owners, editors and creators of the Base the user has installed the extension on. I modified the hello world example but cannot find who is the owners and who are the eidtors and creators. I have:
import { initializeBlock } from "@airtable/blocks/ui";
import React from "react";
import { useBase } from "@airtable/blocks/ui";

function HelloWorldApp() {
  const base = useBase();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {base.activeCollaborators.map((collaborator) =>
        JSON.stringify(collaborator)
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
   
initializeBlock(() => <HelloWorldApp />);
                                                        

And that yields:
{"id":"some_rando_user_id","email":"me@gmail.com","name":"User 1","profilePicUrl":"https://static.airtable.com/images/1.png"}
{"id":"another_rando_user_id","email":"you@gmail.com","name":"User 2","profilePicUrl":"https://static.airtable.com/images/2.png"}

But I have no idea who the owner(s) are, who the editors are, etc. How do I get that info? I've looked through the GitHub docs and their API documentation but can't seem to find it. Thanks!
